# Do AWS charge licence fee for an image based on RHEL AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, rhel, packer

The problem is I bake an AMI with Packer and I use RHEL as a source.

When the image is being baked AWS charge for the Packer VM on pay-as-you-go basis, but when that image is ready and I start using it, do AWS know that it’s based on RHEL? Do they still charge licence fee for it?

Answer (score 3):

**do AWS know that it’s based on RHEL**

Yes exactly, no matter if created it using a packer, as it still bases on some AMI same like Docker base image.

You can check the platform info using aws cli

```
aws ec2 describe-images     --region us-west-2     --image-ids ami-03c752ed9 --query 'Images[].PlatformDetails'
```

or for running instance you can check with
You can check the AMI using AWS CLI bypassing the newly created instance

```
EC2_ID=i-042dbcf65c7bdc3d4 aws ec2 describe-images --image-ids $(aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids $EC2_ID --query 'Reservations[0].Instances[0].ImageId' --output text) --query 'Images[0].Name'
```

**Do they still charge a licence fee for it?**

This is something that depends on the source AMI

```
aws ec2 describe-images --region us-west-2 --image-ids ami-03c752ed931sdf5 --query 'Images[].ProductCodes'
```

You can find price details here for AMI if it from the [market place](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B07Z5GM7W6?qid=1593828613797&sr=0-9&ref_=srh_res_product_title#pdp-pricing) if the source AMI is community AMI then it will be free.

You can also  check further details about RedHat AMI in AWS [redhat FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/partners/redhat/faqs/)